# JSON EXTRACT IN BIG QUERY

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I Currently have a column in json format with multiple items.
The struct is like the following:

> phones": [{"phone": "11111111", "type": "CELLPHONE"}, {"phone":
> "222222222", "type":"CELLPHONE"}, {"phone": "99999999", "type":
> "CELLPHONE"}]

I tried:
**json_extract(Contacts,'$.phones.phone') as phone_number** but it only extracts the first one.

**JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(Contacts,'$.phones') as phone_contacts** gives me an array, But Im getting error trying to unnest it.

Does anybody know any approach to solve this problems?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: json_extract(Contacts,'$.phones[*].phone') : Got an error, saying is not a valid json_path.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select json_value(phone_contact, '$.phone') phone,
  json_value(phone_contact, '$.type') type
from your_table, 
unnest(json_extract_array(Contacts,'$.phones')) phone_contact
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]